# How to wait the end of a firebase call in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

In an android application, i'm trying to do a firebase call that fills an ArrayAdapter in order to show a list of ships.
When i'm using a local ArrayList, it works, but my firebase call doesn't work properly.
Because that firebase call is asynchronous, android shows me the application before ending the firebase call, so my ArrayAdapter is empty and my layout is empty too.
I tryed to use a Coroutine method i've seen online but i doesn't seem to work.
Can someone help me ?
Here is my source code :

MainActivity :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var containerShips : List<Containership> = listOf()
        val db = Database()

        runBlocking {
            containerShips = db.getAllContainerships()
        }




        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, containerShips)

        val listShipDetails = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listShipDetails)

        listShipDetails.adapter = arrayAdapter

    }
```

Database:

```
   suspend fun getAllContainerships() : List<Containership> {
        val list : MutableList<Containership> = mutableListOf()
        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            db.collection("Containership").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (containership in result) {
                    list.add(containership.toObject(Containership::class.java))
                    println(containership.toObject(Containership::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
        job.join()
        return list
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Not a good idea to use `runBlocking {}`, it will freeze UI. Network request, in your case firebase request, may take some time, show some progress indicator or something until the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasks.await to get this done.

```
private fun getAllContainerships(): List<Containership>  {
    return try {
        val taskResult = Tasks.await(db.collection("Containership").get(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        taskResult.mapTo(ArrayList()) { containership.toObject(Containership::class.java) }, null)
    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
        //TODO handle exception
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        //TODO handle exception
    } catch (e: TimeoutException) {
        //TODO handle exception
    }
}
```

Make sure this is done in a background thread. Also, try to get rid of your GlobalScope.async as it is a code smell (to do this, you can use the MVVM pattern, put your data access code in a viewmodel and use viewModelScope from AndroidX lifecycle).